# replace characters in Zsh variable

Tags: zsh

I am trying to replace all the `-` chars with `_` chars in a specific variable. Tried to use the `tr` function. What am I missing?

Thanks!

```
user@mbp-user ~ % echo $APP_ID
app1_someinfo_info-text_text-indfo_text
user@mbp-user ~ % APP_ID= $APP_ID tr - _
zsh: command not found: app1_someinfo_info-text_text-indfo_text
user@mbp-user ~ % APP_ID= $APP_ID tr "-" "_"
zsh: command not found: app1_someinfo_info-text_text-indfo_text
user@mbp-user ~ %
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this without invoking any other processes.

```
$ APP_ID=app1_someinfo_info-text_text-indfo_text
$ echo $APP_ID
app1_someinfo_info-text_text-indfo_text
$ echo ${APP_ID//-/_}
app1_someinfo_info_text_text_indfo_text
```

Or reassign to the same variable

```
$ APP_ID=${APP_ID//-/_}
```

Specifically we are using the pattern

```
name//pattern/string
```

which replaces all occurrences of `pattern` with `string` in the variable `name`.

Comment: Just to note, this works in `zsh` as well, and the syntax is documented in the man page for both shells.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
[user@host ~]$ APP_ID="app1_someinfo_info-text_text-indfo_text"
[user@host ~]$ APP_ID=$(echo $APP_ID | tr "-" "_")
[user@host ~]$ echo $APP_ID
app1_someinfo_info_text_text_indfo_text
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/-/_/g' <<< "$APP_ID"
app1_someinfo_info_text_text_indfo_text
```

Pure `bash`

```
$ APP_ID=${APP_ID//-/_}
$ echo $APP_ID
app1_someinfo_info_text_text_indfo_text
```

Using `awk`

```
$ awk '{gsub(/-/,"_")}1' <<< "$APP_ID"
app1_someinfo_info_text_text_indfo_text
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as below

```
echo $APP_ID | tr -- - _
```

To prevent arguments beginning with `-` from being interpreted as optional arguments, use `--` to indicate the end of optional arguments.

Postscript

But that didn't matter. `tr - _` works as expected. The problem is that you didn't give a string for the standard input of `tr`.